# why can't i access gitlab with my github account?

Tags: gitlab

tried to login with my github access, but once i tried, didn't work at all, it said
------->below the sentence

Sign-in failed because Email is not allowed for sign-up. Please use your regular email address. Check with your administrator..

tried to figure it out many times, but with my own, pretty hard. anybody know this thing?
it'd be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of [sign up restrictions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_up_restrictions.html#allow-or-deny-sign-ups-using-specific-email-domains):

> ### Allow or deny sign ups using specific email domains
>
> You can specify an inclusive or exclusive list of email domains which can be used for user sign up.
>
> These restrictions are only applied during sign up from an external user. An administrator can add a user through the administrator panel with a disallowed domain. Also, note that the users can change their email addresses to disallowed domains after sign up.

Your GitHub access might be associated with a Github email, which is not allowed on your GitLab instance.